# How do I fetch Multiple Specific Rows in Supabase JS?

Tags: javascript, supabase, supabase-database

I have 2 tables Clients and Contacts

I have a table with a cell with specific user IDs in the client table called "contacts"
[image]

How do I fetch the specific rows from the contacts table from the contacts array found in the client table?

Getting the array is easy enough

```
let associatedContactsArray = [];

async function getAssociatedContactsID() {
        const { data: contacts, error } = await supabaseClient
            .from('clients')
            .select('contacts')
            .eq('id', $clientID);
        if (contacts) {
            const [fetchedContacts] = contacts;
            if (fetchedContacts.contacts != null) {
                associatedContactsArray = fetchedContacts.contacts;
                hasAssociatedContacts = true;
                console.log('ASSOCIATED CONTACTS', associatedContactsArray);

                getAssociatedContacts();
            } else {
                console.log('THERE ARE NO CONTACTS');
                hasAssociatedContacts = false;
            }
        }

        if (error) {
            console.log('ERROR GETTING ASSOCIATED CONTACTS', error);
        }
    }
```

The following does not work.

```
    async function getAssociatedContacts() {
        const { data: contacts, error } = await supabaseClient
            .from('contacts')
            .select('*')
            .filter('id', 'in', { associatedContactsArray });
        if (contacts) {
            const [fetchedContacts] = contacts;
            if (fetchedContacts.contacts != null) {
                console.log('GOT CONTACT DETAILS');
                console.log('CONTACTS', contacts);
            } else {
                console.log('NO CONTACT DETAILS');
                hasAssociatedContacts = false;
            }
        }

        if (error) {
            console.log('ERROR GETTING ASSOCIATED CONTACTS', error);
        }
    }
```

I get the error:
    `{ "code": "PGRST100", "details": "unexpected \"[\" expecting \"(\"", "hint": null, "message": "\"failed to parse filter (in.[object Object])\" (line 1, column 4)" }`

Referencing Match the Filter: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [in](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/in) filter for this

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('contacts')
  .select()
  .in('id', associatedContactsArray)
```

Comment: Whenever I do that I get "NO CONTACT DETAILS"

Comment: @ethanfox27 If data is null you should see an `error`. Log your `error` object in the console and you should see what might be wrong.

Comment: There is no error. Error is literally "null" - I don't think it works with arrays. So I am just going to create a separate table with both IDs and fetch all the ones containing the clientID.

Comment: @ethanfox27 If the error is null, then data should not be null, but an empty array. `in` filter should work, but I found that I had an error in my code. I updated my code to use `in` filter with `id` column. Do you want to give it another try?

Comment: Ok you're right - It does work. For whatever reason if (data) doesn't get called, but console.log(data) in the "else" portion returns the data that I need. I gues it has been working this whole time. I should've caught that - Thank you